# Servidor web com raspberry, desempenho

Tags: servidor, redes, raspberry-pi

Bom dia Pessoal!

Estive estudando a possibilidade de criar um servidor web com o raspberry pi 3 b+ e me surgiu a dúvida:

- Considerando que vou publicar sites leves (nenhum de ecommerce ou dashboard), meus clientes vão sofrer algum tipo de lentidão ? 
  *Conexão de 35 download e 3mb upload;

Pretendo usar este meio pelo baixo custo elétrico, visto que o raspberry consome menos q 4 watts e pela experiencia com o projeto

Comment: A velocidade de sua conexão será dividida Conexao/usuarios.

Comment: mas vc acha que teria algum impacto significativo com ate quantos acessos simultâneos?

Comment: isso depende de do poder de consumo de cada um em velocidade. Uma pessoa que tem 40mb de trafego, por ex, consumirá todo seu servidor. mais supondo pessoas que usam 3g, 40 pessoas poderão acessar "SEM MUITOS PROBLEMAS". porem para tudo á uma solução mais inteligente ou menos inteligente. Você procurrar um sistema de balance de rede. e divida bem sua rede para Nº de clientes.

Comment: Sua taxa de transferência precisa ser maior para não ter muitos legs, Sites em html puro vão fluir melhor do que sistemas em PHP, PHP se mau programado vai consumir muito hardware do PI, mas se mesmo assim optar por sistemas em PHP ou outra linguagem de programação, opte pelo servidor web NGINX, ele é mais objetivo em suas configurações, consequentemente consumindo menos recursos de hardware.
Sua pergunta pode ser melhor respondida se postada aqui --> https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlessandroSchneider poxa muito obrigado pela indicação! COmo não será um site muito dinâmico e de baixo trafego, creio que não haverá problemas